Issue with Google OAuth Login using Django Allauth - Bland Account Selection UI
I'm working on a Django project where I've integrated Google OAuth login using the django-allauth package. The functionality works in terms of authentication, but I'm encountering an issue with the user interface during the Google account selection process.
please do tell me where I've made a mistake, I'm a student please don't expect me to have good knowledge about Django.
Problem:
When users click on the "Sign in with Google" button, they are redirected to a Google page for authentication. However, instead of the usual Google account selection UI (which typically shows account avatars and a modern design), the page appears bland and basic, lacking any styling or proper UI elements.

==>What I've Tried:
-->Checked Django and django-allauth versions:
Django version: 5.0.7
django-allauth version: 0.63.6
-->Setup in settings.py:
I've configured the necessary settings for django-allauth, including setting up the social account providers.
-->Login Template (logipage.html):
I'm using a custom login template with buttons for "Sign in with Google" and "Sign in with Outlook."
-->Browser Console & Network Tab:
Checked for any errors or missing resources but found none.
-->Updated Packages:
Made sure all packages, including django-allauth, are up-to-date.

when clicked sign in with googlesignin with google
when selecting accounts (this is ok cuz it has ui )account selection ui
this is after selecting accounts after selecting acc
what i want it to look like
this is how its normally like right? normal look

please don't comment your own question, [edit] it.

My best guess is that a user, probably the superuser you created to login to the admin panel, is still logged in.  See what happens you log out, and try it again.  You can also try to modify this in your settings.py to automatically connect a a social account to a regular account:
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
  'google': {
      'EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION': True
  }
}

The page you are seeing is the one found here.  It is among many of the account templates that ship with django-allauth, and if you want to style / change these in any way, they can be overridden easily.  A nice tutorial on this can be found here, or you can search "overriding django-allauth templates" and find other resources.
